# Как сделать чтобы алгоритмы программы могли ссылаться на продолжительность ее работы?

Tags: c#

В моем понимании, мне требуется неким образом использовать секундомер на форме, соответствующий общему времени работе программы, чтобы при нажатии на TButton, вызванный алгоритм мог ссылаться к времени работы программы и вследствие выполнять различные действия.

VS 2015, C#, Windows Forms.

Answer (score 2):

Гораздо лучше будет обойтись без таймера, а обращаться за этой информацией к процессу программы.

```
public DateTime GetProcessStartTime(string processName)
 {
     Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
     if (p.Length <= 0) 
     {
        throw new Exception("Process not found!");
     }
     return p[0].StartTime;
 }
```

[Process.StartTime Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.starttime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Запустите Stopwatch (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
Start();
...
Stop();
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
```